# Component-wise convergence of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Suppose we have a sequence of a $m \times n$ matrices.

Define the operator norm of a matrix $A$ as $\lVert A \rVert=\sup\{\lVert Av \rVert : \lVert v \rVert \leq 1 \}$ where we use the Euclidean norm for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively.

Then convergence can be defined in terms of this matrix norm in the usual way.

I think that we could alternatively define convergence component-wise. My idea for a proof is to use the following properties of the matrix norm:

$(1) \lVert A \rVert \leq mn \max \{\lvert a_{ij} \rvert : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ and

$(2) \lVert a_j \rVert = \lVert Ae_j \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert$ where $e_j$ is the jth unit vector and $a_j$ is column $j$ of $A$

For example from $(1)$ we can prove that if each component of a matrix sequence converges, then the matrix must converge to the matrix with all of the limits as its components.

$(2)$ gives the reverse implication, i.e. if a matrix sequence converges to a matrix, then each column vector must converge to the respective column vector of this limit matrix, and in turn this also holds for each component of those column vectors.

Similarly, this should also hold for Cauchy sequences or continuity of matrix-valued functions.

Is this proof idea correct?

Comment: When you write $\Vert v \Vert$, what norm are you using on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Just the Euclidean norm, but it should not really matter since all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ah, I think I can see your point now. $e_j$ might not have norm 1 in a different norm?

Comment: The proof is correct. All norms on $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ are equivalent and, as in all finite normed vector spaces, convergence $A_n\to A$ occurs iff the components $a_{ij}$ converge.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Also note that $A_{ij}=\langle Ae_j,e_i\rangle$ so the claim follows from the continuity of the inner product.